# Adding direct reference to a WCF project

Tags: wcf

Wondering if somebody done it before. We are using WCF in our current architecture and when internally not going over the boundaries I would like the ability to reference the project directly.

I don't want to use tcp or named pipes, I would like to know if is technically possible to alternate between a project reference or normal communication with WCF eg tcp-http etc..

Is there any example or approaches to achieve this?

Looked on google and stackoverflow but I could not find an answer if the title was the same

Many thanks

Comment: Well, you *could* have an assembly that contains your business logic, and a WCF service on top of that. Then internally, you could connect directly to those business objects, while externally you're talking to the WCF service which then in turn uses those same business objects, too, to do its work

Comment: I see.Thanks that will work,just thinking loud,what about adding references at runtime when internally(eg a setting in the config)